# When I destroy an ExtJs grid object its kept in the initialconfig, causing a massive memory leak, how do I get rid of this initialconfig properly?

Tags: javascript, extjs, memory-leaks, extjs4.2

I'm creating a grid inside a panel, and when I destroy the grid a reference to it is kept inside the initial config for the panel, meaning it's not ever cleaned up properly. Is there a way to stop this initialconfig from even being created/a way to clear it so hat objects it holds references to will be correctly cleaned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can null it in Base destructor. Unfortunately Base is not a real class so overriding it via `Ext.define` is not the proper way but we can work around that with a closure:

```
(function() {
    var oldDestroy = Ext.Base.destroy;

    Ext.Base.destroy = function() {
        this.config = this.initialConfig = null;
        oldDestroy.call(this);
    };
})();
```

I would **strongly** advise you to upgrade to Ext JS 6 if memory leaks are a problem in your app. We plugged most of the component leaks in 6.0, and unfortunately this effort is largely not backportable without major compatibility issues.